# About 17% chance

Tags: riddle, word

Another riddle for you.

Clue 1:

> I got highs but I also got lows

Clue 2:

> People are interested in me only for some value...

Clue 3:

> Also, people told me that I'm worse than a double-sided person...

Clue 4:

> Usually, I make noise when in movement

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> A die? (A six-sided die, specifically?)

Clue 1:
I got highs, but I also got lows

> A die has numbered faces from 1 (lows) to 6 (highs).

Clue 2:
People are interested to me only for some value...

> If you’re rolling for high numbers, people only are interested in dice for those specific numbers; they are not used often except for gambling/games.

Clue 3:
Also, people told me I'm worse than a double-sided person...

> It’s harder to guess the outcome of rolling a die (1 in 6) than the outcome of flipping a two-sided coin (1 in 2).

Clue 4:
Usually, I make noise when in movement

> Dice do make noise when rolled.

And the title:

> If trying to guess the outcome of rolling a six-sided die, you have about a 17% (16.66666%) chance of doing so.

Comment: Congratulations! This is a really well-explained answer in terms of clues and details related, also it feets exactly what I was thinking about, keep up the great work!

Comment: I disagree @El-Guest, I think the fourth line is just there to make the riddle longer, the first line is not creative, there is a grammar mistake in the second line, and the third line doesn't make sense because I don't see how a dice is worse than a coin because it's harder to guess the outcome.

Comment: @RustEnigMachine I strongly disagree with you. It isn't great riddle but still it is a good one. The definition of creative depends upon person to person. It might be different for you than me. I think grammar mistakes in these sort of riddles are trivial. Third one is a bit of pun because we generally don't like double faced person and a dice has six outcomes. But still I will say that it depends upon person to person. Sorry for a long comment.

Comment: @RustEnigMachine still I have fixed some grammatical errors which I have spotted but they won't be visible until some reputed user checks it.